# Mouse pointer teleportation to the default dialog button

Tags: windows-10, logitech-mouse, wireless-mouse

I upgraded to an MX master and while the new Options software is good, it is missing a few features from SetPoint. The one I need is the ability to "teleport" the mouse pointer to the default button of a dialog window.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this on windows 10. Maybe some 3rd party utility?

Setpoint won't recognize the MX master.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have the mouse snap to the default button in a dialog is still possible in Windows 10.

Click on `❖ Start` → Type in: `Mouse Properties` → Click the `Mouse & touchpad settings` listing.

From the *Settings* window that appears:
Click on the `Additional mouse options` link → Click on the `Pointer Options` tab → Tick the *Snap To* option `Automatically move pointer to the default button in a dialog box`.

Comment: great, I missed that when I was searching for it.

Comment: What a horrible feature. Thanks for telling me how to turn it off.